Syntax highlighting in macOS terminal during program installation
During compilation of a program in the macOS terminal, the output text is highlighted in several different colours to indicate different things. For example:

I have been searching for a while now and I cannot find any mention of what this type of syntax highlighting/colouring might be called or referred to as (or how to replicate it in a GitHub post). The only other posts I can find discussing syntax highlighting are about enabling it in the terminal in general, or vim.
Does anyone know what this type of highlighting might be called? I do not think I set it up manually, so I do not know if it is a result of the compilation software or something else... (For context, this was an attempt at installing a program written in Rust using the command cargo install.)

What do you mean with "what is it called"? Looks like the compiler used uses Terminal color codes to indicate errors and warnings.

@nohillside So it's not caused by the compiler, just the Terminal settings?

The compiler triggers it by sending the ANSI color codes required to switch the color shown in Terminal. The Terminal itself just shows text in whatever color the compiler requests, it has no knowledge of the content itself.

@nohillside Ahhhh, I did not realise they did that. In hindsight it makes sense... Maybe submit that as an answer and I'll give it a tick.

A terminal application doesn't know anything about the content (text) it displays, so the color coding is driven by whatever application is running inside. In your example, it's the Rust compiler which uses ANSI color codes to switch color based on the context.
You can use the same codes also to colorize your shell prompt. echo -e '\033[31;1m!\033[0m will for instance show a red exclamation mark.
